# Как прочитать сжатый (gzip) ответ на GET-запрос (C#)?

Tags: c#, get

Имею дело с запросами на C#.
Запрос отправлен с `Accept-Encoding: gzip`. Получаю ответ в `StreamReader`, но сжат в `gzip`, поэтому ответ через `StreamReader.ReadToEnd()` прочитать не выйдет.
Как же его расшифровать? (убрать сжатие не вариант)

Набросок кода дабы понимали о чем я:

```
var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        httpWebRequest.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding: gzip");
        using (var httpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse())
        {
            using (var stream = httpWebResponse.GetResponseStream())
            {
                using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.GetEncoding("UTF-8")))
                    return reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте **GZipStream**  [GZipStream - класс (MSDN)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.io.compression.gzipstream(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
 var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        httpWebRequest.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding: gzip");
        using (var httpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse())
        {
            using (var stream = httpWebResponse.GetResponseStream())
            {
                using (GZipStream gzipStream = new GZipStream(stream, CompressionMode.Decompress))
                {
                    using (var reader = new StreamReader(gzipStream, Encoding.GetEncoding("UTF-8")))
                    {
                       return reader.ReadToEnd();
                    }

                }

            }
        }
```